# Commutator subgroup is the minimal normal subgroup such that quotient group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I was recently asked this in Abstract Algebra class on group theory:

> Let G be a group and G' its commutator subgroup (i.e. its minimal subgroup containing all commutators $ [x,y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1} $ where $ x,y \in G $ ). Where are asked to show G' is the minimal normal subgroup such that the quotient group $  G/G' $ is Abelian (if $ H \unlhd G $ and G/H is Abelian then we must have $ G' < H $)

To be honest I have tried but could not seem to be able to solve this. I have shown G' is normal and quotient group $ G/G' $ is abelian, but I cannot prove G' is minimal normal subgroup with this property. I really would appreciate the help on this. Thanks all

Comment: Which part is the problem? Showing that the quotient is abelian or that $G'$ is minimal with this property?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : it is showing that $ G' $ is minimal with this property of all normal subgroups, I have shown quotient group is abelian

Comment: So take some normal subgroup $N$ and assume that $G/N$ is abelian. Write up what this means in terms of commutators.

Comment: @AbeerAbassi If $\phi\colon G\to A$ is a homomorphism and $A$ is abelian, what can you say about $\phi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})$?